# shell_exec() not returning correct results using Git-Bash

Tags: php, git, shell

I am trying to `exec` Git Bash through PHP `using shell_exec()`. The command i am attempting to insert in is `shell_exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -c "br -algorithm AgeEstimation \ -enroll C:/Users/Username/S354-01-t10_01.jpg C:/Users/Username/S001-01-t10_01.jpg metadata.csv"')`. This returns `Unrecognized function -algorithm`

This will not return the correct results to PHP, but if i just use `shell_exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -c "br -help"')`, it will return a page containing Core, Miscellaneous and other commands (for the library).

Please need help using shell_exec.

Comment: Can you try by giving absolute paths to the jpg and csv files.

Comment: @web-nomad i have edited my question with an absolute path.

Comment: What is the command `br`? From the looks of it, it's trying to run that command like: `br -algorithm AgeEstimation -enroll C`.....
So the error is br saying there's no -algorithm

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou , i am very new to Git-Bash, and using that line in Git-Bash returns the correct results, any solution on how to return the correct results through php (i.e. executing Git-Bash via PHP and using `br -algorithm AgeEstimation...` as some sort of parameter?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. In order to use the `shell_exec('some commmand')`, I had to specify the directory to open the shell in before executing `shell_exec()`. This was done by using PHP's `chdir('C:\users\userFolder')`. This provided me with the correct results, i hope someone else finds this helpful.